# Rikulo websockets and channels

Tags: dart, rikulo

Does rikulo stream v 0.7.2 support web sockets with different channels?
I have seen so far only examples with static resource files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle Web Socket, you can use [WebSocketTransformer](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_io/WebSocketTransformer.html) to *upgrade* HTTP connection to WebSocket connection:

```
new StreamServer(uriMapping: {
  "/cmd", (HttpConnect connect) =>
      WebSocketTransformer.upgrade(connect.request)
      .then((websocket) {
        websocket.listen((evt) {
          websocket.add("Server received: $evt");
        });
        return socket.done;
      })
}).start();
```

> Note: Web Socket is supported directly since Rikulo Stream 0.8.0. Please refer to [the WebSocket Handling section](http://docs.rikulo.org/stream/latest/Request_and_Response/WebSocket_Handling.html).

Comment: big thx for the answer and the links. At first glance it does not look trivial :/. I guess that I will have to read the whole documentation?